# It takes more than 30 secs to load the Jenkins URL from a browser

Tags: jenkins, hudson

It takes more than 30 seconds to load the Jenkins URL in a browser.  What are the things I should check/modify to fix this issue?

Comment: Which version of Jenkins are you using ?  How many total jobs and builds do you have ?

Comment: About 30 jobs running. The version is 1.509.1.

Comment: Is it the first time you load Jenkins after it's started?It could take long the first time

Comment: Not just the first time, every time. How should I go about debugging this sort of issue?

Comment: @MkKm: are you installed jenkins locally?

Comment: @MkKm: Please clear all events in event Viewers application tab ( in control panel) and close the browser and try agin

Comment: Is this the root URL or a job URL ? Do you have non standard views with maybe some extra columns ? What plugins are you using ?

Comment: Is your Jenkins deployed in tomcat? See the log to find out the reason

Comment: There can be lots of little causes.  The big ones I have seen are things like dashboards that aggregate job build histories coupled with  lots of jobs with lots and lots of history.  Page loading slows down because there is so much data to process.

Comment: @Sumeshk, Jenkins is installed on Mac mini. It is not my local machine.

Comment: The slowness is with the root URL. The URL uses :8080.

Comment: Plugins installed are Mailer, External monitor job, ldap, pam authentication, Ant, javadoc, credential, maven, ssh credential, ssh slaves, subversion, jenkins translations assistance

Comment: I don't have tomcat installed.

Comment: I did not set up custom views. Just the "All" view/tab.

Comment: @MkKm:Clear the build history and try again

Comment: I probably should not clear all of the history completely because it is a shared machine . I kept 200 builds per job and cleared the rest of really old builds. Not much change with the URL loading speed.